# TextInput get value by reference react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to retrieve user input inside a functional component (I am using a `redux` architecture). However when I `console.log()` a referenced item, I get a constructor, not the actual object.

How can I get the user input without manipulating state?

```
  <Modal visible={visibleModal === 'addRoom'} onRequestClose={() => null}>
    <TextInput ref={el => {roomName = el}} style={styles.input} />
    <Button onPress={() => store.dispatch(hideModal())}>Cancel</Button>
    <Button onPress={() => {
      store.dispatch(addRoom({name: roomName.value}))
      return store.dispatch(hideModal())
    }}>OK</Button>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: Based on the docs `TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c} ` , you both need to return that value, and probably use this. to see it on the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the value of a TextInput by ref with React Native. The only way to get the text from an input is to subscribe to change events.

Answer (score -6):

Try `.value` when you access your TextInput through `ref`

Comment: This may work on React web with an <Input> element, but it does not work on React Native